# I have "TypeError: Cannot call a class as a function" with EditorJS in NextJs

Tags: next.js, editorjs

I have a problem to include EditorJs in my NextJs app.
I've tryed this :

Editor.js

```
    import dynamic from "next/dynamic";
    
    let CustomEditor = dynamic(() => import("./CustomEditor"), {
        ssr: false,
    });
    
    export default function Editor() {   
    
        return (
            <>
                {CustomEditor && (
                    <CustomEditor
                    />
                )}
            </>
        );
    }
```

CustomEditor.js

```
import EditorJS from "@editorjs/editorjs";

const CustomEditor = () => {

    return (
        <EditorJS  />
    );
};

export default CustomEditor;
```

But I have this problem :

[image]

What can I do to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You are not using "editor-js" correctly. Look at the [docs](https://editorjs.io/getting-started). `EditorJS` is not a function/class component; thus, it can't be used. I suggest you try [react editor js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-editor-js) instead. It has pre-defined components that you can use easily as so:

```js
import { createReactEditorJS } from 'react-editor-js'

const ReactEditorJS = createReactEditorJS()

<ReactEditorJS defaultValue={blocks} />
```

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm testing right now, but it still doesn't work even following the doc. I would eventually make this editor work. Thank you for your contribution!